# RPi mouse frequent timeout?

Tags: mouse

Mouse frequently "times out" and is non-functional for a period of time from a few seconds to indefinitely (requiring reboot). Generally happens during a burst of high CPU activity and mouse is functional a second or two after burst.  But sometimes the mouse stays non-functional indefinitely until reboot.

I'm running the latest updated Raspbian and openbox desktop, generally running amateur radio communication progs in terminal-- quite low CPU overhead. But I-net attached.

Any suggestions would be appreciated-- eg, is there a convenient way to increase the mouse polling priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a power supply issue. If you have to many things plugged into the USB, then it drops exactly like that. The built in USB is limited in it's ability to take power from the power supply meant for the CPU.

Suggestions

-A Powered USB hub will solve this problem if you're using a USB radio

-Turn off the HDMI output and disable 'boot to desktop' in raspi-config

-Use keyboard instead of mouse (terminal only)

Comment: Thanks!  --right on, it worked.  I was using a 1amp wall-wart USB supply but it was going through an un-powered 4-port hub which, apparently, was current limiting.